# Evaluate the sign of an integration

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

Let $P_k(x)$ to be the first $k+1$ terms of the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$, that is 
$$P_k(x) = \sum_{l = 0}^k (-1)^l x^{2l}/(2l)!.$$
For $\alpha>0$ and $\alpha\notin \mathbb{Z}$, I want to evaluate the sign of the following integration:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos(x) - P_{[\alpha]}(x)}{x^{2\alpha+1}}dx,$$
where $[\alpha]$ is the largest integer not larger than $\alpha$.

I have done some simulations and it seems the sign is $(-1)^{[\alpha]+1}$, which is the sign of the dominant term of the remaining Taylor series, but not fully sure about that. I wish someone could come up a solution for this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Too long for comment**

You already know that 
$$\cos x=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

So naturally,
$$\begin{align}
R_m(x)&=\cos x-P_{m}(x)\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq m+1}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\end{align}$$
And when we define
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x-P_{\lfloor \alpha \rfloor}(x)}{x^{2\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx$$
We see that 
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty R_{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{2\alpha+1}}$$
$$I(\alpha)=\sum_{n\geq \lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_0^\infty x^{2n-2\alpha-1}\mathrm dx$$
But I do not know if this method is valid, as the final integral does not seem to converge...

Comment: Thanks for comment! Surely the final integral doesn't converge, but this doesn't mean $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)-P_{[\alpha]}(x)}{x^{2\alpha+1}}dx$ is not well defined. To see this, you should consider divide it into three parts, $\int_{0}^1\frac{\cos(x)-P_{[\alpha]}(x)}{x^{2\alpha +1}}dx$, $\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{2\alpha +1}}dx$ and $\int_{1}^\infty\frac{P_{[\alpha]}(x)}{x^{2\alpha +1}}dx$. And each of them are finite. The last two parts are easy. The first is because $(\cos(x)-P_{[\alpha]}(x))=O(x^{2[\alpha]+2-2\alpha-1})=o(x^{-1})$ as $x\to 0$.